# 'ListNode' object is not iterable

Tags: python, linked-list, quicksort

I'm practicing my programming skill on Linkcode.
I'm doing a sorted list problem in which I need to Sort a linked list in O(n log n) time using constant space complexity. I want to use quicksort algorithm to do that.

I got the error message: "Traceback (most recent call last): File "/code/Main.py", line 20, in ans = solution.sortList(head) File "/code/Solution.py", line 21, in sortList dummy, tail = self.quickSort(head) File "/code/Solution.py", line 91, in quickSort dummy1, tail1 = self.quickSort(start) TypeError: 'ListNode' object is not iterable"
I'm really confused because I'm not using anything for iterable in line 91. I'm just passing a 'listNode' object into the recursive function which ask a 'listNode' input. Can anyone help me to see what's the problem?

here is my code:

```
"""
Definition of ListNode
class ListNode(object):
    def __init__(self, val, next=None):
        self.val = val
        self.next = next
"""

# quicksorting
class Solution:
    """
    @param head: The head of linked list.
    @return: You should return the head of the sorted linked list, using constant space complexity.
    """
    def sortList(self, head):
        # write your code here
        if not head:
            return None
        if head.next is None:
            return head
        dummy, tail = self.quickSort(head)
        return dummy.next

    def quickSort(self, start):
        dummy = ListNode(0)
        dummy.next = start

        if not start:
            return None 
        if start.next is None:
            return start

        slow = start
        fast = start.next

        while fast:
            if fast.next:
                fast = fast.next.next
                slow = slow.next
            else:
                break

        mid = slow
        pivot = mid.val 

        left = start
        leftPrev = dummy
        right = mid.next
        rightPrev = mid
        Tail = mid

        while left != mid and right:
            while left != mid and left.val < pivot:
                left = left.next
                leftPrev = leftPrev.next
            while right and right.val > pivot:
                Tail = Tail.next
                right = right.next 
                rightPrev = rightPrev.next

            if left != mid and right:
                self.changeNode(left, right, leftPrev, rightPrev)

                temp = left 
                left = right 
                right = temp

        while left != mid:
            if left.val <= pivot:
                left = left.next
                leftPrev = leftPrev.next
            else:
                nextLeft = left.next
                self.insertNode(left, Tail, leftPrev)

                Tail = Tail.next 
                left = nextLeft

        while right:
            if right.val >= pivot:
                right = right.next 
                rightPrev = rightPrev.next
                Tail = Tail.next
            else:
                nextRight = right.next
                self.insertNode(right, dummy, rightPrev)
                right = nextRight

        midNext = mid.next
        mid.next = None
        dummy1, tail1 = self.quickSort(start)
        dummy2, tail2 = self.quickSort(mid)

        dummy.next = dummy1.next
        tail1.next = dummy2.next 
        tail2.next = None

        return dummy, Tail

    # insert node2 to node1.next of a list
    def insertNode(self, node1, node2, prevNode2):
        nextNode2 = node2.next
        node2.next = node1.next
        node1.next = node2
        prevNode2.next = nextNode2

    # exchange position of node1 and node2 of a list
    def changeNode(self, node1, node2, prevNode1, prevNode2):
        nextNode2 = node2.next
        prevNode1.next = node2
        node2.next = node1.next
        prevNode2.next = node1 
        node1.next = nextNode2
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `quickSort` method is supposed to return a `tuple` (which is iterable) as you do at the bottom with `return dummy, Tail`, so that the multiple assignment

```
 dummy1, tail1 = self.quickSort(start)  
 # return value must be iterable (producing exactly two elements)!
```

can work. In the two if-blocks at the top of said method

```
if not start:
    return None   # not iterable!
if start.next is None:
    return start  # not iterable!
```

however, you return `None` or `start` (both of which are not iterable), for which the above assignment will fail with the error that you are seeing.